# Ad-Hoc distribution - The application "<application name>" was not install on the iPhone "<iPhone name>" because the signer is not valid

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

what does it really mean when itunes complains that??

The application "" was not install on the iPhone "" because the signer is not valid.

we have got this error when we use "Build and Archive" or even with "Ad-hoc" distribution method with the targeted iPhone's UUID registered with Provisioning portal and generated new provisioning profile before we build the binaries...

then we will ship the binaries via email to our tester... they will try to install the application and this error always appear.

any idea what happened?

Comment: I think that @PARTH is correct. It has to be one of the reasons @PARTH has given.

Comment: @Anjali : those are the things that i already know.. and unfortunately they do not solve my problems.. cos those are the things that i have ensured that i have done it every time i package the binaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yit Ming:

**There can be three issues:**

**1)** It may be the case your provisioning profile either has expired.

**2)** It may be your app is not code signed with a proper provisioning profile.

**3)** It may be the case that your device ID may not be added to the provisioning profile.

Hope this helps

Comment: @ PARTH 1) the provisioning profile is newly created. 2) we can install the app into some iPhones using different computer, but when we send it to our tester, they could not install the app into their iPhone using their computer  3) the device ID is definitely added to the provisioning profile and the we re-create the provisioning profile after that

Comment: @Yit Ming: Ok so did you try deleting your profiles and redownloading and creating a new AdHoc?

Comment: @PARTH : actually sometimes deleting the new profile and compiling the binaries again and send to the tester's PC does work. But what happened? they kept asking why did all these happened and how can we mitigate it?

Comment: Yeah actually that can be avoided.You can just create your ipa using "Build and Archive" and then "save it to disk". I dont say that this is 100% working solution but it decreases the chances of this kind of error by 95%. So it is more efficient way of doing this. Also you can use the same distribution certificate and try and install it first in your own device before sending it to the client. So that you can be sure that there are no issues with Code Signing and Profiles. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Yit Ming: Did this help you?

Comment: @PARTH: actually i was using that method first.. but my tester kept hitting the signer is not valid error.. that's y i changed to use ad-hoc distribution which is more troublesome compared to Build and Archive

Comment: Nope that are the only two options.

Comment: @PARTH.. sorry.. it doesn't help.. cos i m still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

i have already found a solution to my problem.

as i mentioned previously, even if i use the method "Build and Archive" to compile a binary (in .IPA) to be installed in my tester's device, occasionally i will still get the error

The application "" was not install on the iPhone "" because the signer is not valid.

This is because the provisioning profile is not being installed properly to the device... (you can verify whether your provisioning profile is being installed by Settings -> General -> Profiles)

What i have done to resolve this issue is, i will copy my provisioning profile and .ipa file to my tester.

Then my tester will drag both of the files into his iTunes.

This will ensure that the provisioning profile is being installed to the device. then woalla!