# warning when archiving file to IPA

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uikeyboard

I am getting the following warning:

```
"This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier"
```

Why is this? Googling for this I found out that I need to follow the provisioning steps more closely, I did that. I am using 4.3.3.

Comment: seems like some issue with info.plist . Can you check out by viewing it in xml key value format . You might find some thing wrong at bundle id .

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501795/entitlements-are-not-valid-error-while-installing-ad-hoc-build-on-device)

Comment: I have it like this for the <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>Aditya-Herlambang.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>

Comment: I've read all that Rayfleck and it didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved the exact problem by editing my Entitlements.plist.I found out how/why in this [post](http://andresdouglas.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/the-application-identifier-entitlement-is-not-formatted-correctly-problem-when-submitting-your-iphone-app-to-the-appstore/).

You can edit your Entitlements.plist as a property file (see Pranav's answer) or you can edit it directly as I did.

My Entitlements.plist now resembles this:-

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC “-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN”             “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd“>
<plist version=”1.0″>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXXX.com.bakodo.BakodoScanner</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: now it presents another issue, warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Comment: well - you're one step further! ;-) It now sounds like you need to check your distribution certificate. The best way I have found to get 'coherent' messages about what is going wrong during code signing is to use Build&Archive and then Validate the resultant build. Anyhow both Pranav & I both answered your original question so I believe we deserve an upvote! Please amend your question with the second problem or even start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Entitlements.plist file which we ADD before transferring the application on to the device. it should contain the APP ID & . & bundleID.

[image: R5GSK7J37W is APPID, KitabooM is BundleID]

Comment: where can I see options like that? I only have can be debugged on my Entitlements.plist

Comment: Qn. Do you have an Entitlements.plist in your project? If not you need to ask Mr. Google about adding it to your project....

Comment: yes I do have it...but I don't have the application-indentifier

Answer (score 0):

I solve this! Now I can say: This is a BUG of Xcode 4.

All the problem start when you include "Entitlements.plist" (or the name you create) in "Code Signing Entitlements" After this, all things start to have a problem.

What I want is distribute it with Ad-Hoc distribution. So, I [fallow this paper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html). Now the why this is a bug. When I am working in a project that was create in XCode 3, this work fine (I am using it in my XCode 4.0.2). When I do this in a project that was create in XCode 4, this annoying message appear.

How to solve this: First let's imagine you have all "Code signing" working, you will only write this in "Entitlements.plist" (Open it in "source code" mode)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/   PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>322ZQ37PJY.br.com.yourcompany.yourprogram</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
         <string>322ZQ37PJY.br.com.yourcompany.yourprogram</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

The < string> need to be the exact you have in your app ID in "iOS Provision Portal", in other words, you will need use your identifier more the random code of it site. Dont forget the key **get-task-allow**, you will need use it to make the Ad Hoc distribution (and set it to FALSE).

This solve my problem... One entire day to discovery it... :(

Answer (score 0):

1) Select "Product" in Top Menu of xCode
2) press ALT on keyboard and Select "Clean Build Folder" in submenu of "Product".
3) Rebuild your App.